# Cookies are not working in Google Chrome but working in other browsers like Edge, IE

Tags: c#, cookies

I am working on Cookies. It was earlier working with all browsers, but now stopped working with Google Chrome and is still working with other browsers like Edge, IE.

Below is my code.

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_crt"];
if (cookie == null)
{
    cookie = new HttpCookie("_crt");
    cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    List<Cart> list = cart.AddItemToCart(cart, new List<Cart>());
    cookie.Value = cart.EncryptCartItem(list);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

}
else
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_crt"].Value))
    {
        List<Cart> list = cart.AddItemToCart(cart, new List<Cart>());
        cookie.Value = cart.EncryptCartItem(list);
    }
    else
    { cookie.Value = cart.EncryptCartItem(cart.AddItemToCart(cart, cart.DecryptCartItem(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_crt"].Value))); }
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Comment: How are cookies "not working"? Are they not being received? Not being stored? Chrome's developer tools console will show a warning message if it sees an invalid or deprecated cookie.

Comment: Hi Dai, cookies not received

Comment: If they're not being received then it means your server isn't sending them. Are you sure this code is being executed for those requests?

Comment: Hi Dai, Actually same is running with other browser like IE , Edge, Firefox

Answer (score 4):

Current versions of Chrome (e.g. v86 *) will reject to save a cookie with `SameSite=none` and `Secure=false` (or unset), see @Pskyco s reply.

Also, if you serve a site via HTTP (NOT HTTPS) Chrome (and other browsers, tested for Firefox) will not save secure cookies. So, consequently it is not possible to set a `SameSite=none` cookie via HTTP in Chrome (as they always have to secure)!

* *everything >=v80, according to https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site*

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. Since few days, a simple HttpCookie doesn't work anymore, but only on mobile throught browser.

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(CST_IDENTIFICATION_COOKIE)
{
   Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),
};
[...]
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Btw, I got the answer directly from Chrome console.

> A cookie associated with a resource at
> http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/ was set with `SameSite=None` but
> without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies
> marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can
> review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies
> and see more details at
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

I had to set the property 'Secure' of the cookie to 'true' to make it works.

```cs
cookie.Secure = true;
```

Comment: There's no reason this would be the reason: browsers still accept session-only cookies (i.e. cookies without an expiry, so they're deleted when the user closes all windows/tabs for a website).

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Cookies.Append("jwt", jwt, new CookieOptions
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Secure = true,
                        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
                    });
```

Comment: https://cdmana.com/2021/04/20210401214557999u.html#:~:text=%22Migrate%20entirely%20to%20HTTPS%20to%20have%20cookies%20sent%20to%20same,appear%20when%20POSTing%20a%20form.

Comment: could you please add a description to your code Ghadir?